# Getting CSS :hover on overlapping siblings

Tags: html, css

This is easiest to understand when running the code below. I'm looking to trigger the hover state on both a column and the middle row when hovering over the red bar.

I'd like to keep the columns based on flex and have the bar absolutely positioned over them.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

I'd like just the column that the mouse is hovering over to turn blue. Sorry for the ambiguity. Snippet updated with desired result.

The columns are divided by a white line. Hover over a grey area to see the column highlighted.

Thanks.

```css
.root {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.column:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 33px;
  bottom: 33px;
  background: red;
}

.bar:hover {
  background: green;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
Hover over the middle of the square. I want the middle column to turn blue and the bar to turn green.
Right now, only the bar turns green.

<div class='root'>
  <div class='column'>
  </div>
  <div class='column'>
  </div>
  <div class='column'>
  </div>
  <div class='bar'>
  </div>
</div>

Desired result: 

<div class='root'>
  <div class='column'>
  </div>
  <div class='column blue'>
  </div>
  <div class='column'>
  </div>
  <div class='bar green'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Final Edit:

I'm providing a fully fleshed out version of what my use case is. I don't think CSS will be able to solve this, but I've accepted an answer that works for my original question.

```js
function enterColumn() {
  document.getElementById('column-status').innerHTML = 'In column'
}

function leaveColumn() {
  document.getElementById('column-status').innerHTML = 'Out of column'
}

function enterBar() {
  document.getElementById('bar-status').innerHTML = 'In bar'
}

function leaveBar() {
  document.getElementById('bar-status').innerHTML = 'Out of bar'
}
```

```css
.root {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.column:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.bar-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 33px;
  bottom: 33px;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
}

.bar:hover {
  background: green;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
Hovering over a column or bar should be independent. Right now you can never have the 'In column' and 'In bar' status at the same time :(
<br />
It should scale to support any number of columns and any number of bars (where bars can be absolutely positioned anywhere along the x-axis)
<br />
Javascript events should be called on mouse events for both columns and bars.

<div class='root'>
  <div class='column' onmouseenter='enterColumn();' onmouseleave='leaveColumn()'>
  </div>
  <div class='column' onmouseenter='enterColumn();' onmouseleave='leaveColumn()'>
  </div>
  <div class='column' onmouseenter='enterColumn();' onmouseleave='leaveColumn()'>
  </div>
  <div class='bar-container'>
    <div class='bar' style='left: 5px; right: 40px' onmouseenter='enterBar();' onmouseleave='leaveBar()'>
    </div>
    <div class='bar' style='left: 65px; right: 5px' onmouseenter='enterBar();' onmouseleave='leaveBar()'>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id='column-status'>
  Out of column
</div>
<div id='bar-status'>
  Out of bar
</div>
```

Comment: CSS has no way of knowing _where_ an element is being hovered, so this is more than likely not going to be solved by CSS alone.

Comment: @chazsolo I was hoping for something like a pointer event that behaved like pointer-events: none but still triggered the :hover selector and onmouseover javascript event. Starting to look like I'll have to use javascript for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go, after 2 hours of trial and error I finally came up with this little hack.

```css
.root {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border-right: solid #fff 1px;
}

.column:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.column .toggle{
  margin-top:33px;
  height: 33px;
  width: 100%;
}

.column .toggle:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 34px;
  height: 33px;
}

.column .toggle:hover:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 33px;
  bottom: 33px;
  background: green;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 33px;
  bottom: 33px;
  background: red;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<div class='root'>
  <div class='column'><div class='toggle'></div></div>
  <div class='column'><div class='toggle'></div></div>
  <div class='column'><div class='toggle'></div></div>
  <div class='bar'></div>
</div>
```

Now if you need to bind some javascript events to the `.bar` element, attach them to `.toggle` instead.

Comment: It will change the background of all the columns, not just one

Comment: Fixed it, let me know if it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Clever hack. I'm accepting it even though it won't work for my use case. I should have stated that the bar going across could contain multiple bars and they should trigger javascript events. I'll update my question with my actual use case, but I think it I'm trying to push CSS too far. I'm giving up on having this exact ability.

Answer (score 1):

If rearrangement of `divs` is allowed, you can position the `.bar` just before the middle `.column` and use adjacent sibling selector.

```
.bar:hover + .column {
     background: blue;
}
```

```css
.root {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.column:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 33px;
  bottom: 33px;
  background: red;
}

.bar:hover {
  background: green;
}

.bar:hover + .column {
  background: blue;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='root'>
  <div class='column'>
  </div>
  <div class='bar'>
  </div>
  <div class='column'>
  </div>
  <div class='column'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you did not quite understand the question. It's a bit ambiguous. OP wants the hover effect to affect not only the central column, but all three.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean, you mean that if you hover over any element the `.column` should turn **blue** and `.bar` should turn **green**. If that's the case then actually its pretty simple. Just place your `hover` event on `.root` element instead like so:

```css
.root {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 33px;
  bottom: 33px;
  background: red;
}

.root:hover .bar {
  background: green;
}

.root:hover .column {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='root'>
  <div class='column'>
  </div>
  <div class='column'>
  </div>
  <div class='column'>
  </div>
  <div class='bar'>
  </div>
</div>
```

If that' not the case and you want the color of the `.column` to change when you hover over the `.bar` then check out the snippet below. Note that I've a changed the HTML markup a bit. Since `.bar` has `position: absolute` so it won't affect at all where you place it inside the `.root` element.

```css
.root {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.bar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 33px;
  bottom: 33px;
  background: red;
}

.bar:hover {
  background: green;
}

.bar:hover ~ .column {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='root'>
  <div class='bar'>
  </div>
  <div class='column'>
  </div>
  <div class='column'>
  </div>
  <div class='column'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if that helps you :-)